# Show Userforms Based on Different Cell Formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a department game that will add up points and show UserForms based on the total points awarded. For example, cell A1 (Player 1) should display UserForm1 when the cell reaches 50-99 points (sum(A2:A10)). Once they reach 100-149 points, it will show UserForm2, and this continues up to 1000 points.

I am having some trouble with the Worksheet_Calculate portion of the VBA. If Player 1 reached 50 points and then later Player 2 reaches 50 points (Cell B2) the UserForm1 should only show once for Player 2. Instead, with the code I am working on now, UserForm1 shows twice because both arguments are true. I am having trouble 'stepping out of' the first if statement and having the code only reference Range("B1") without testing the if statement for Range("A1"). Also, with my current code, if Range("A1") is not greater than 50 but Range("B1") is, UserForm1 does not show.

All the research I can find only shows how to fix this problem if you have one player using If...Then...Else and nothing about if there are multiple players.

Below is the code I am playing with (early stages as until I solve this problem, I can't write the rest of the userforms into the code).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

If Range("A1").Value >= 50 And Range("A1").Value < 100 Then
UserForm1.Show
Else
End If

If Range("B1").Value >= 50 And Range("B1").Value < 100 Then
UserForm1.Show
Else
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `If (Range("A1").Value >= 50 And Range("A1").Value < 100) Or (Range("B1").Value >= 50 And Range("B1").Value < 100) Then` ?

Comment: That worked. I'm going to update the code and start building out the rest of the tiers and userforms. Thank you!